# Prevent merge when Heroku review app build fails

Tags: github, heroku, circleci

We are using Github + CircleCI + Heroku with automatic deploys setup.

From time to time there are deploy errors that are not captured by CI (deployment fails event though CI run is fine). We have review apps set up for all our PRs.

It would be great if the PR would indicate this and stop us from merging if the deployment of the review app fails (that usually means the deployment of the staging/production app would also fail).

I could not find any documentation on this. The only possible way I see is to use the GitHub API to add a custom check for this.

Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Looking for this myself too, did you find anything?

Comment: Unfortunately not ...

Answer (score 2):

We have made a GitHub Action to test the deployment status of a Heroku Review App: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/heroku-review-app-deployment-status.

This can be used in the GitHub workflow to test the deployment status.

UPDATE: We wrote a nice blog post about different approaches to verify Review App deployment status.

Link: https://blog.niteo.co/staging-like-its-2020/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Github's protected branches for this https://help.github.com/en/articles/enabling-required-status-checks

Navigate to your repository's settings -> Branches -> Add Protection Rule -> Select "Require Status Checks Before Merging" and select "CircleCI".

In order for this to work you need to cause CI to fail if your deployment fails. If you get a failure from Heroku, you should run any command that will return `exit 1` as a status code, which will fail CI for you.

Comment: CircleCI has no context of Heroku review app deployments and hence cannot know when or if to fail the build.

Comment: Why not deploy the heroku review apps from CI then, instead of Github automatic deploy?

Comment: Because that's not trivial. It's much harder than, for example, creating a bot that checks if deployments are fine and reports to GitHub.